# What's the equivalent of int32_t in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

What's the equivalent of int32_t in Visual C++?

Comment: Visual C++ has that, just include <cstdint>

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Visual C++ 2010 include `<cstdint>`, which includes typedef `std::int32_t` (you can also include `<stdint.h>` which has the same typedef in the global namespace).

If you are using an older version of Visual C++, you can use [Boost's `<cstdint>` implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/boost/cstdint.hpp).

Answer (score 8):

What I do is make my own typedefs after making sure the types exist like so:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #if _MSC_VER >= 1600
        #include <cstdint>
    #else
        typedef __int8              int8_t;
        typedef __int16             int16_t;
        typedef __int32             int32_t;
        typedef __int64             int64_t;
        typedef unsigned __int8     uint8_t;
        typedef unsigned __int16    uint16_t;
        typedef unsigned __int32    uint32_t;
        typedef unsigned __int64    uint64_t;
    #endif
#elif __GNUC__ >= 3
    #include <cstdint>
#endif

typedef int8_t      s8;
typedef int16_t     s16;
typedef int32_t     s32;
typedef int64_t     s64;
typedef uint8_t     u8;
typedef uint16_t    u16;
typedef uint32_t    u32;
typedef uint64_t    u64;
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have a pre-`cstdint` version of Visual Studio, you can use [`__int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

`int`. But, if you want to continue using the stdint typedefs in VC++ versions prior to 2010 (in which the `cstdint` header was introduced), consider using [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Config](http://www.boost.org/libs/config/)'s [cstdint implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/cstdint.html).

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but note that int32_t is signed. So you probably should have just said: `int`, as it is 32bit on VC.

Comment: I don't believe that you are guaranteed a 32-bit `int` for every architecture that VC compiles to.

Comment: @user470379 : Since VC++ 1.52, it is in fact guaranteed that `int` is 32-bit. And if you're using a version of VC++ earlier than that, then I suspect you'll have larger issues than `sizeof(int)` to worry about ;-]