# What's the equivalent of int64_t, int_least16_t & uint8_t in Visual C++ 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the equivalent of int32_t in Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657825/whats-the-equivalent-of-int32-t-in-visual-c)

What's the equivalent of **int64_t** , **int_least16_t** and **uint8_t** in Visual C++ 2008?

Comment: Yes I am the one who asked that question :P

Comment: I'm using Visual C++ Express 2008 and I can't use <cstdint>

Comment: You can use the Boost `<cstdint>` implementation.

Comment: I took a look at it but no idea what's written. May be because I'm new to C++.

Comment: Why did you accept my answer to your other question if it didn't solve your problem?  In any case, you can find the ranges of the fundamental types [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx).

Comment: @kevin: Since you're using the express version anyway, you have nothing to lose upgrading to 2010.  Why haven't you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- int64_t: __int64
- uint8_t: unsigned __int8
- int_least16_t: __int16

Answer (score 6):

```
int64_t        __int64
int_least16_t  short int
uint8_t        unsigned char
```

Comment: ohh !!! Is it the same answer with the above answer?